# Windows 8 developer ID

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

While I know how to create a developer ID through the windows 8 powershell, I can't tell how things will work when I get to the publishing to the windows store, since currently it's only open to a small number of select developers.
https://appdev.microsoft.com/StorePortals/en-us/Account/Signup/SelectAccountType?wa=wsignin1.0

My question is, how does the windows 8 developer account tie in with the windows 8 developer ID (windows live account).  Are they one in the same?  I started to go through the creation process in the link above and it seemed like I would be creating a seperate account......

Answer (score 0):

your live id and windows store id is linked .Only through live id you can access windows store.

Developer id & live id are linked .